# Make a model from image

Tags: modeling, image

I have been trying to put an image in blender so I can make a 3d model of it but it does not seem to show up. Any good tutorials for blender 2.71 to show me how it is done? Thanks

Comment: Welcome on Blender.SE, tutorial requests are off-topic. Do you just want to set the image as background image?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing if you want something else please add this to your question, or in case you face any problems, otherwise this would be a duplicate and closed.