# How do I get a constant Background Image?

Tags: image

Not only in ortho: top, front, back.

Please don't link this answer [How do I set a background image while I am editing?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing)

I want a background image like this guy has ->
https://youtu.be/M-RJ6tYrPmE?t=3m31s

Comment: i think he just imported an image as plane

Comment: How do you do that? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: Empty image can be seen in all views except render (even solid and wireframe) with modifiable transparency, image as plane can be seen only in texture, material and render view

Answer (score 2):

Go to the file --> user preferences --> add ons --> type images --> import images as planes --> check the checkbox

[image]

Then you can go to file --> import --> images as planes. Or in the 3D view <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> --> mesh --> images as plane

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of the video the author clearly says **"I just added an image empty"**...

Add>Empty>Image.

Then select the image you want the empty to use.

[image]

[image]

All of this is cleary stated on the answer you linked: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/314/1853

Answer (score 2):

Add an *Empty* (press *<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->Empty-->Image*).
[image]

Under the *Properties* header in the *Empty* panel click on ***Open***.
[image]

Adjust the *transparency* of the image.
[image]