# Background Images not showing up!

Tags: 3d-view

I'm new to blender, and I've already gone to many forums looking for a solution to this problem. Please help!

Comment: welcome @PastelPuff. Please take a few minutes to look through the Rleated Links to the right on this page. If none of those get to the heart of the problem please _edit_ your question with more information, the steps you go through, and preferably a screenshot. As it stands there are many ways to interpret your seemingly simple question.

Comment: With so little info on the question is hard to imagine what is going wrong. Please edit your post and tell us how you set up your scene and the background image in question, inform us  if the problem is during rendering or during preview, if you are using cycles or blender internal, if your image is in a format supported by blender, if this happens when you are on orthographic view or perspective view... Are you using the compositor? As you can see there are a few possibilities but without your help is going to be impossible to determine which of the many reason applies to your scene.

Answer (score 3):

You have to ensure that you are in [Orthographic View](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/navigate/3d_view.html?highlight=orthographic) or [Camera View](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/navigate/camera_view.html?highlight=camera%20view) to see [Background](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/background_images.html?highlight=background%20images) images. To toggle between Perspective and Ortho views press <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> and Type <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> for Front view (or <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> for Right or <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> for top view). To use camera view press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>

Comment: If you want to see your images in perspective, try using an empty. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing

Comment: @cegaton thanks for the edit :) Anyway, my first answer here ;)

Comment: @JanScherders keep them coming!