# How can I achieve a domed or "hangar" type cross-section shape?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Warning: I'm a day-two Blender user.

Specifically, I want the long, straight edges on the top face of the mesh to sort of "merge down" with the same edges on the bottom face (essentially, reduce it to one edge instead of two), with the curved ends ending up with flat bottoms and topsides curved in an even arc.

This shape was imported as an SVG, extruded and then converted to a mesh, but the geometry of it is super janky and overcomplicated-- WAY too many triangles and vertices. Ideally, the top face would simply be a series of long thin faces that line up with the sides. I tried to simplify the mesh in a couple of ways, but it didn't pan out and now I'm stuck. Should I just be reconstructing this shape some other way, or is this shape I've imported salvageable?

[image]

EDIT: I've been asked to clarify the end shape I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a drawing or picture of the end result you are looking for?

Comment: Just picture it like this: The entire thing is curved over the top and flat on the bottom, terminating in sharp sides where the long edges of the shape are. So the ends would look like if you made a horizontal cut across the top of a circle.

Comment: Sorry, that doesnt help.

Comment: Added a drawing for clarification.

Comment: If that's the contour of the desired object, you can draw it in Ortho view with vertices and then extrude the result. Use [background images](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing) to ease drawing.

Comment: Not really-- It's important that the shape of the object seen in the top ortho view is maintained. A half-cylinder is somewhat close, but then I have to model the curves in at the short ends. I was hoping that someone would be able to advise me concerning the original imported shape that was extruded and converted to a mesh, but that part of the question hasn't stimulated any response.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> Select *Add a Mesh* then select *Add a Circle* from the drop down menu. You can change the number of vertices in the tool bar on the left.

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go into *Edit Mode*. Select the number of vertices desired to delete bye selecting them and then pressing <kbd>X</kbd> and then vertices from the drop down menu.

Select the bottom two vertices and press <kbd>F</kbd> to connect them.

Select all of the vertices and press <kbd>E</kbd> and then press the letter of the axis you want to extrude them along. For example press <kbd>E</kbd> and then <kbd>Y</kbd> to extrude along the Y axis.

[image]

Comment: While I was gone, I was playing around with a cylinder, which I cut down to accomplish basically the same thing (I can create faces to close the object, so that's no problem). Now, the job seems to be figuring out how to recreate the curves on the top ortho view of the shape.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think the original answer, and comments were useful to this question, but I'm not certain this is the way I'd approach it myself, because many times other methods are faster, and more future proof.

Sometimes modifiers can make the workflow faster, without touching all of the vertices. In this case a simple Boolean>Difference modifier works well.

If I don't apply and delete the bool subtraction object, I can come back later and adjust for future edits.

[image]

Hope that helps expand your mind a little.

Kind Regards,

RRiggs

Comment: For Clarification: The bottom 'Half-Cone' was spun 180° so that you can see, it closed the surface. The modifier was applied correctly.

Comment: There sure is more than one way to skin a cat! I find that, in some cases, as meshes get more complicated Boolean Modifiers can be very tricky. It is great to know all the options though. Thanks for your answer.