# Background images not showing up at all in persp or ortho view

Tags: interface, image

I cannot get background images to show up. From what I understand you add the background image, then set the view it shows up in and then use numpad to set your camera view, yet this does not work for me. I've tried the 'ortho' and 'persp' views, along with the 'front', 'back' and 'sides' angles using the numpad, but cannot see any image. Also, setting which view the image shows in has no effect.

I have also tried dragging and dropping a image in, with no luck. I understand I can also add a image to a empty plane, but even this way does not work.

On the other hand, when it comes to adding materials and textures to objects, everything looks fine in edit mode and the final render, so this is not a problem.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing/314#314

Comment: What format is the image you want to use? Can you share such image? What  kid of computer and Graphics card are you using? Are you getting any error message on the console? Can you import the image into the UV/image editor?

Answer (score 6):

## Background images will only be displayed in:

1. Camera Prespective view (<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>)
2. Any of the **preset** Orthographic views:

   Front/Back (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>)

   Right /Left (<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>)

   Top/Bottom (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>)

To toggle between Prespective and orthogonal view use <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Background images have a transparency Slider. When it is set to 0% the image will not be visible.

Also the image will only Show up in the viewport, not the final render

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble getting my image to show up, in spite of all my research. I followed instructions to the 'T'. As it turns out, my image was there and visible, **BUT I had to increase the SIZE of the image considerably!** You can find SIZE at the bottom of the Background Image properties in the Properties panel.

Answer (score 0):

these are the views that you can use to place a background image, according to your needs, usually vast with the frontal and lateral

[image: Background Image]

Comment: You do understand this is a two year old question and the user has probably moved on by now?

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old question I would have appreciated this info. My images would show up in the drop down list and while some images worked, the broken image's thumbnail would be blank. I found that blender is picky with the file format. If you save images off of the internet and they wont load into blender, try opening the image in paint.net (or some other image editor) and "save as" and just overwrite the old image.

Answer (score 0):

Check viewport overlays.
Make sure the extras option is ticked.

I nearly forgot I did that while searching. Figured to share this in case anyone had a similar case.