# Blender Background Image Issue

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, image

Background Images are not showing up in the other views other than the camera view. It will show in the camera view but not in the other orthographic views. I have tried switching the set view that the image is visible in and increasing opacity to 1.0. I am in orthographic view when I am attempting this.

Here are the specs for my computer that I am aware of:

- Blender Version: 2.78
- Image format: jpeg
- Graphics Driver: NVIDIA
- OS: Windows 8.1

Edit: Here is an image of the setup. Nothing is changed except for the preset view (using left in this case).

[image: Current setup with only Left Preset view]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Do you use preset orthographic views or do you enter in User orthographic view with Numpad5 ? Also please include set up of your background image; it could happen it's chosen to be shown in camera view only. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing

Comment: Background images show only in PRESET ORTHO views (Front, Back, Left, Right, Top, Bottom) or Camera Perspective. No user Ortho views will display background images.

Comment: I tried all the preset ortho views. I am a bit of a noob so I didn't know about the preset and user ortho views.

Comment: To find out whether background images can be shown choose *All Views* and enter one of either preset views or camera view; thus you'll see do background images work or not. See about [entering preset ortho views](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122/1245).

Comment: That is what I initially did. It was set to the default All Views with no other settings altered. I did what was shown in the preset ortho view tutorial and the image did not show. When I selected the camera view instead of All Views and went into camera view it showed.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me in all views using 2.78 build 2016-8-11. On Windows no special driver and I have a sucky standard display chipset that gives me OpenGL grief. You're sure that its in Ortho mode?