# Transparent Image As Plane While In Sculpting Mode

Tags: image, sculpting

I want to use images as planes to assist with sculpting. *Sometimes images that I have to use are not straight on and having a plane allows me to align the mesh to the angle the image is in.*

So far...

**1. I've imported the image using the *import image as plane* add on.**

[image]

Now I want the image plane to be transparent.

**2. I hit 'n' key and change image plane shading from textured to GLSL.**

**3. I change the *viewport shading* to texture.**

**4. Under the materials tab for the image plane, I've changed the transparency.**

All it good at this point because the image is now transparent.

[image]

The problem is when I...

**5. go to sculpt mode...**

the image is no longer transparent. How do I keep it transparent in sculpt mode so I can use it as a reference image?

Comment: Use either background image or add [empty image](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/314/1245).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling X-Ray on the Display panel for the plane will keep it transparent in sculpt mode.

[image: Isaac Newton]

Answer (score 0):

I believe is a limitation with sculpt mode, but if you want to use a reference image, you can still use the background image feature for the 3D view. This doesn't add a mesh object, but it works fine for reference images (actually what it is intended for).

[image]

https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/display/background_images.html