# Can't See Background Image on Ortho View

Tags: 3d-view

I'm trying to import a background image, and it shows the file name, but it does not show up. I put it in Ortho view but it still wouldn't show. I tried with lots of images just to make sure the image was corrupted or something.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of 3d view and background image panel?

Comment: make sure, that the viewport view matches your view setting of your background image, so both top for example

Comment: Do note that background image will be visible only in *preset* orthographic views (Numpad1, Numpad3, Numpad7). See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing

Answer (score 2):

**Background images will only be displayed in**

> Camera Prespective view (<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>)

Any of the **Preset** Orthographic views

> - Front/Back (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>)
> - Right /Left (<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>)
> - Top/Bottom (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>)

Background images will not show in perspective view.

To switch between Perspective and Orthographic view use <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>

Background images are used for reference only and will not be part of the final render.