# How to change the visible angle when using a background image

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, image

So I'm trying to model using a background image and I really need the front face of the image to be facing the same direction as the z axis.

Comment: From your quite short description it *seems* that you'd like to see background image in the Top Ortho preset view (Numpad7). Setup the background image properly (image settings > Axis > Top or Bottom) or add image empty or Image as Plane. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing

Comment: you can make the background image appear only in a specific axis. By default is set to all views but you can make it be top, bottom, front, back, left right or camera.

Answer (score 1):

After adding the [background image](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/properties/background_images.html) to the 3D view simply change the axis the image is displayed on.

[image: background image settings]