# Front Mesh making back mesh impossible to see, help?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm modeling a 3d figure from a set of 2d images.  I have most of the front done using a background image as a reference and using the mirror modifier.  I used a right side reference image to do the sides.  Now that I'm working my way to the back of the figure, the front and side mesh are confusing the new mesh i'm making for the back. I tried hitting 'z' to show the faces, but then I can't see my reference image.  There has to be a trick to do this.  Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a background image while I am editing?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing)

Comment: Screenshots are the best way to show what do you want to ask. "the front and side mesh are confusing the new mesh i'm making for the back" doesn't correlate well with modeling *one* 3d figure you started from

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the vertices you don't want to see. Just select the ones you want to hide and press <kbd>H</kbd>.

Also, the reference image will only show when you're aligned with an axis and in [orthographic mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/projections.html)—hit <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>, or <kbd>7</kbd> on the numpad to align the view, and then <kbd>5</kbd> to go into orthographic mode.*

<sub>*The manual says that orthographic mode is the default in Blender, but it's not.</sub>