# I cannot see my background image

Tags: image

This has really bugged me, I am trying to follow a tutorial on modelling but **I cannot see my background image**. I have gone through many youtube videos but everything they suggest, I have already done. I am in orthographic mode, I am in front mode (I set it to appear in all views) and I've set the opacity to 0.5.

Here's a screenshot of my screen.
[image: My screen]

Comment: Looks like it is set up correctly. What format is your background image in? Try some other .jpges just as proof of concept that you can display something.

Comment: It seems that you have no color space (indicated 'color' in your screen capture followed by an weird empty choice)... try to change (if any value in that list)

Answer (score 1):

As Lemon mentioned in the comments,

You dont seem to have a color space.

Its weird it even let you have a blank one. 
Maybe try choosing the drop down, if that doesnt work try restarting Blender.

Just choose sRGB if you dont have Filmic.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Background images work with cameras, push the `Numpad 0` button to set the camera in view. 2.76b and you can also use `Numpad 5` to switch view mode

```
Num 0
```

[image: Camera view]

Comment: Can also press the numpad 5 key to set to ortho which is how the views need to be for background images not using the camera.

Comment: Background images work not only with cameras, but also in any of the **preset** ortho views. Read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122/1853 Note even if the view is set to ortho but not in the preset (front/back, left/right, top/bottom) views the background image will not be displayed.