# How can I project an image on a face for editing

Tags: edit-mode, image, faces

I have the following face:

[image]

I want to put an image on it to use it to trace a pattern on it that I will later extrude. Everything I keep finding is to put an image for rendering, but i want to do so for editing.

Comment: maybe add the image as backround image?

Comment: Background image sounds exactly what you need, you can use Images as Planes add on too and make it transparent in viewport.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing/122#122

Comment: An alternative is to use the UV project modifier: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBv3N40LG-o