# how to move the camera without making the reference background image disappear?

Tags: camera, image

I am modeling something off an image. But I don't know how to move the camera without making the image disappear. How do I do that?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing

Answer (score 2):

You can use an empty as image

[image]

Select the image in the properties->Empty->Display tab

[image]

You'll get your image (or video) in an empty. The advantage of this method is that your image will be visible as you rotate, and is visible even in when the 3D viewport shading is set to wireframe or bounding box.

Note that empties will not be rendered on the final render...

[image]