# Aligning model with background image

Tags: image

I have this image of Chicago and then an open street map of the same district. 
What are my chances of aligning the image with the street map?
Any advice would be very welcomed as I've been rotating and scaling it for an hour or so.

[image: Chicago]

Comment: Open street maps are mostly flat, and have imprecisions and inaccuracies. Real world is curved, the terrain has features, and camera lenses distortions so it might well be very hard to achieve a satisfactory result, though certainly not impossible. That being said you definitely should be rotating and adjusting a camera object, rather than introducing distortions on your correctly scaled import; that will only worsen things.

Comment: Also, you need information on the lense used for taking the photo which can be put in Blender. If you try to adjust with an arbitrary lense setup (32mm sensor /35mm focal length being default, it will be extremely difficult to align it manually. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG9pN.png

Comment: related: [How do I align my grid to background footage?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40308/how-do-i-align-my-grid-to-background-footage/40330#40330) and [Tips For Modelling From Google Maps?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97108/tips-for-modelling-from-google-maps?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: to find the lens used on the picture you could try using [Blam](https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam)