# View Reference Images In All 3d Views

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, image

I recently watched a [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ja56zOdZhRQ) that used two images simultaneously for front and side views. The images don't disappear when the speaker moves around the 3d-viewport. It's a little difficult for me to explain it in words, please watch the video to look at the image orientation.

I would love to know how that kind of image reference would be possible, because when I load any images they're only visible in one view and disappear when I switch the view.

Please let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: It's likely added as an [empty of Image type](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/314/1245) or via Images as Planes addon (shipped with Blender)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that is not the case, he is using one image for the front view and one for the side view and as he is switching between views using a short key so its look like he has background image for every view

Background image is disappeared in many views, take a look below:

[image]

Comment: Try Num pad, 1 and 3 for the respective view switching

Comment: What happens on [1.04](https://youtu.be/ja56zOdZhRQ?t=1m4s) clearly shows that's not a background image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch view using Num pad 1 and 3 and you will get consistent background image for front and right side view