# Materials only showing in some views

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I am using blender 2.79 and I have a material with the color of purple. The color shows in one of my views but not the other.

[image]

Comment: Looks like there's a background image in the viewport on the left which has violet color for one of its parts. As that viewport is in some of preset ortho views (front or side) background image can be seen but it won't be in the other viewport as that one is in perspective mode. Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing.

Comment: Are you using matcaps?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you are on the **Material** Under **Viewport shading**,

As shown below:

[image]