# Blender rotates images that are being added in the UV image editor

Tags: image, uv-image-editor

For some reason, blender rotates some images when I try to add them in the UV image editor for reference. How can I fix this? Thanks.

[image: How images should appear/appear in windows explorer]

[image: How images actually appear in blender]

[image: How images appear when added in the UV image editor]

Comment: Images in thumbnails are often handled with EXIF data in the image which can be treated differently / unexpected by file manager. What happens when you actually add images into UV editor, how are they displayed? As of now they are displayed by File Explorer, not UV editor

Comment: Same result as the thumbnails I should've mentioned sorry.

https://i.imgur.com/undefined.png

Comment: Then most likely easiest way is to rotate image in some image editor program and import re-saved image, as it looks like Blender doesn't read EXIF data about rotation (or it's written somewhat incorrect). By default Blender itself can't rotate image in UV editor. Or you can stick to using Images As Planes addon or empty images in viewport instead, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing