# resizing reference after giving specific dimensions

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model a room from reference images. I know it's exact sizes,
and can change it to that in the properties. The reference picture will not change with that of course, how do i resize and place the reference in the correct way?

Comment: Answer greatly depends on what do you mean by "reference picture". Convenient way of interacting with images in viewport is with Images As Planes addon or empty images. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing for info on different ways to setup reference images

Comment: try this. after resizing the mesh, note the new scale. then paste that scale into your reference image.

Answer (score 1):

How about

1. create a plane
2. assign it a texture with your ref image (some UV mapping/unwrapping required to match the entire image)
3. Size it and use it in the background in Ortho view
4. repeat for front/side views with different pictures!

[image]