# Modeling buildings - size and scale

Tags: modeling, scale

I am interested in modeling buildings (houses, office buildings, etc.) But the main problem I'm having is figuring out the right size of everything. Like, how tall the door should be, the distance between floor and ceiling and ceiling to floor, and so on. I don't know anything about architecture and I'm pretty OCD (which is probably part of the problem). I'm just wondering if there is some kind of guide to figuring that out or if someone can help me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Blender SE. :) This may sound a bit obvious but its what i have in a drawer of my desk..... A 3meter retractable tape mesure. If I want to know the hight of a table ...... the hight of the lower edge of a window,  the thickness of a wall,the hight of a doorway,  the depth of a step ........I just get up and mesure it. Never fails. And also mesuring it yourself you get a better feeling for the size of things.

Comment: You can always take a picture of an existing building, and use that as a background image allowing you to model.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about using Blender

Comment: In architecture we often use the [Neufert book](https://archive.org/details/Architectural_Standard_Ernst_Peter_Neufert_Architects_Data) as reference for measurements